# FindInstance with a Diophantine equation seems to go on forever

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

I tried to find a non-trivial integer solution to the equation
$$2012^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2$$
with Mathematica but the computation takes minutes; I might be doing something wrong.

```
FindInstance[2012^2 == a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 
    && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0, {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers]
```

But when I try

```
FindInstance[2012^1 == a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 
    && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0, {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers]
```

I get an immediate result.

Comment: @kguler the change was from 2012^2 to 2012^1, I think they are both meant to be from the Integers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It does not seem surprising that a search space 2000 times larger results in a substantially longer computation time.

Here is a much more direct way to find a solution:

```
Sqrt @ IntegerPartitions[2012^2, {5}, Range[2012]^2, 1]
```

> ```
> {{2011, 63, 7, 2, 1}}
> ```

Comment: +1 for the clean approach. Though all *odd* (small enough) powers of 2012 work fast. Try this `FindInstance[2012^13 == a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2, {a, b, c, d, e}, Integers]` On the other hand *even* powers work slow. I am not sure if it is exactly larger computational space issue.

Comment: @Vitaliy that's an interesting observation.  I don't feel qualified to analyze the reason.

Comment: Mathematica seems to pick the wrong approach, i tried replacing 2012^n with other values and in most of them i ran out of memory, even if the number is very small like 864

Answer (score 18):

Here is a way to make `FindInstance` work and give you a a few random solutions quickly:

```
Flatten /@ ({a -> #, FindInstance[2012^2 == #^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2, 
{b, c, d, e}, Integers]} & /@ RandomInteger[2011, 10]) // Column
```

[image]

Your equation can be solved for any `Abs[a] <= 2012`. Here is an app that let's you browse random solutions for any such fixed `a`

```
Manipulate[FindInstance[2012^2 == a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2, 
{b, c, d, e}, Integers, RandomSeed -> s], {{s, 300, "sample"}, 1, 
1000, 1}, {{a, 345}, 1, 2012, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Do you mean higher even powers by "more general"? If yes, the above approach works with any even power.

Answer (score 8):

As it happens, I wrote code for this sort of thing a couple of months ago. Am hoping to put it into Wolfram|Alpha some day.

```
sumOfPowers[n_, pow_, use_, exactly_: False] := 
 sumOfPowers[n, pow, use, n + 1, exactly]
sumOfPowers[n_, pow_, use_, min_, exactly_: False] := Catch[Module[
   {n1 = min, nminus, res},
   If[use == 1 && ! IntegerQ[n^(1/pow)], Throw[$Failed]];
   If[n <= min && IntegerQ[n^(1/pow)] && (use == 1 || ! exactly), 
    Throw[{n}]];
   While[(n1 = Floor[n1^(1/pow)]^pow) > 0,
    nminus = n - n1;
    res = 
     sumOfPowers[nminus, pow, use - 1, Min[nminus, n1] + 1, exactly];
    If[res =!= $Failed, Throw[Prepend[res, n1]]];
    n1--;
    ];
   $Failed
   ]]
```

Your example:

```
In[6]:= sumOfPowers[2012^2, 2, 4, True] // Timing

Out[6]= {0.11, {4040100, 7396, 324, 324}}
```

To find all such sums, perhaps best would be to use

```
PowersRepresentations[2012^2, 4, 2]
```

This might be no faster than what you did, though.