# Trouble getting FindInstance to return multiple results for certain constraints

Tags: equation-solving

I'm having a hard time getting `FindInstance` to return multiple results. Consider this simple example:

```
FindInstance[a > 0 && b >= 0 && c >= a + b && a >= c/3 , {a, b, c}, Integers, 2]
```

Mathematica (8.0.1 on Mac) quickly returns

```
{{a -> 244, b -> 206, c -> 618}, {a -> 306, b -> 299, c -> 860}}
```

Good. But if I change `c/3` to `c/4`, which only relaxes the constraints, Mathematica goes busy for 18 sec. For a little more complicated case (9 variables with 15 similar constraints) it never returns (I left it running for several days).

Asking for one solution for the `c/4` case (and for the 9 variable case) gets an immediate result:

```
FindInstance[a > 0 && b >= 0 && c >= a + b && a >= c/4, { a, b, c}, Integers, 1]
```

returns

```
{{a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 3}}
```

What accounts for the difference?

*One more edit:* for completeness, here's the 9 variable case:

```
FindInstance[{a0 >= 0, a1 >= 0, a2 >= 0, a3 >= 0, a4 >= 0, a5 >= 0, 
  a6 >= 0, a7 >= 0,
  nn == a0 + a2 + a4 + a6 + a1 + a3 + a5 + a7,
  (a1 + a3 + a5 + a7) / nn >= 0.5735, (a1 + a3 + a5 + a7) /nn  <= 0.5745,
  (a2 + a3 + a6 + a7) / nn >= 0.4715, (a2 + a3 + a6 + a7) / nn <= 0.4725,
  (a4 + a5 + a6 + a7) / nn >= 0.5225, (a4 + a5 + a6 + a7) / nn <=  0.5235,
  (a3 + a7)           / nn >= 0.2325, (a3 + a7)           / nn <= 0.2335,
  (a6 + a7)           / nn >= 0.2775, (a6 + a7)           / nn <= 0.2785,
  (a5 + a7)           / nn >= 0.2655, (a5 + a7)           / nn <= 0.2665,
  ( a7)               / nn >= 0.1195, (a7)                / nn <= 0.1205
  },
 {a0 , a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 , a6, a7, nn}, Integers, 2]
```

I tried a few variants, such as replacing the decimals with fractions and expanding `nn`, to no avail.

Comment: After 18 seconds I get `{{a -> 343, b -> 570, c -> 1003}, {a -> 520, b -> 826, c -> 1648}}` on mine (8.0 on win32).

Comment: Yeah, me too (same configuration as wxffles)

Comment: @wxffles thanks for trying it. I updated the Q. After the bigger problem took days I started equating 5 seconds with infinity. I do get an answer after 18 secs, too. Still, I wonder what makes the 3 -> 4 change take so much longer.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3554/121

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When requesting multiple instances larger values for each variable are produced:

```
FindInstance[a > 0 && b >= 0 && c >= a + b && a >= c/4, {a, b, c}, Integers, 5]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 536, b -> 909, c -> 1960},
>  {a -> 353, b -> 420, c -> 1237},
>  {a -> 403, b -> 762, c -> 1472},
>  {a -> 709, b -> 933, c -> 2337},
>  {a -> 543, b -> 956, c -> 2040}}
> ```

I suspect this larger search space is the reason for the slow behavior.  There may be an option that controls this but I am not aware of it.  I have a couple of ideas for working around this.

### Get one instance at a time

The idea here is to restrict the set to exclude each solution as it is found, then ask for one instance.

```
par = {a > 0, b >= 0, c >= a + b, a >= c/4};

f = Or @@ Unequal @@@ 
  First@FindInstance[par~Join~#, {a, b, c}, Integers, 1] &;

List @@ Rule @@@ # & /@ Nest[Append[#, f@#] &, {f@par}, 7]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 1, b -> 0, c -> 3}, {a -> 2, b -> 0, c -> 4}, {a -> 3, b -> 0, c -> 5},
>  {a -> 4, b -> 0, c -> 6}, {a -> 2, b -> 1, c -> 5}, {a -> 2, b -> 0, c -> 3},
>  {a -> 3, b -> 0, c -> 3}, {a -> 2, b -> 1, c -> 4}}
> ```

These results are produced much more quickly, again I suspect because of a smaller search space.

### Add an upper bound

With knowledge that solutions are possible with small values:

```
par2 = {15 > a > 0, 15 > b >= 0, 15 > c >= a + b, 15 > a >= c/4};

FindInstance[par2, {a, b, c}, Integers, 100] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.016, 100}
> ```

So 100 solutions may be found almost instantly within the restricted space.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use Reduce previously to simplify (and somewhat generalize) your problem.

```
r[n_Integer] := Evaluate@Reduce[a > 0 && b >= 0 && c >= a + b && a >= c/n, {a, b, c}, Integers];
FindInstance[r[4], {a, b, c}, 100]
```

The answer is very quick.

Comment: Great answer.  I'm a bit annoyed with myself for not trying that.  Nevertheless I know from past experience there are times it does not help, and other measures are required to coax results from `FindInstance`.

Comment: By the way you can use `Set` and drop the `Evaluate@`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right. Also, if you examine the output of `Reduce[a > 0 && b >= 0 && c >= a + b && a >= c/n, {a, b, c}, Integers]` , you will see that _this time_ Evaluate[] is luckily finding a neat expression for Integer and positive n.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `FindInstance` uses different methods to find 1 instance and to find more than one instance.

```
constraint = {a > 0, b >= 0, c >= a + b, a >= c/4};

Trace[
 FindInstance[constraint, {a, b, c}, Integers, 1],
 _Reduce`LinearDiophantineInstance | _Reduce`ReduceInstance,
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Trace[
 FindInstance[constraint, {a, b, c}, Integers, 2],
 _Reduce`LinearDiophantineInstance | _Reduce`ReduceInstance,
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`LinearDiophantineInstance` returns quickly, even on the 9-variable problem.  The second call to `ReduceInstance` in the 2-instance case takes a long time, which is easy to believe given the complexity of the auxiliary system.  In the 9-variable case, I only waited a few minutes while, I assume, it was building the argument for a second `ReduceInstance` call.

I do not know whether there is a reason to use `ReduceInstance` instead of nested calls to `LinearDiophantineInstance`, similar to [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) approach. Given that it handles both of the examples, it seems unlikely.