# What Method options does FindInstance accept?

Tags: functions, equation-solving, options, undocumented

While answering [Trouble getting FindInstance to return multiple results for certain constraints](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6781/121) it became clear that for this problem `FindInstance` would be better starting with small numbers, but it does not.

The function has the `Method` option:

```
Options[FindInstance, Method]   (*  Out: {Method -> Automatic}  *)
```

Yet, I cannot find documentation for the methods (and methods sub-options) that it accepts.

- What `Method` values does `FindInstance` accept?
- Will any of them scan an `Integer` search space small-values first?

Comment: A perusal of ``??System`InstanceDump`* `` might provide a few clues, I think.

Comment: Related> Here there are a few options for `FindInstance[]` mentioned http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RealPolynomialSystems.html

Comment: @J.M. that command yields ``Information::nomatch: No symbol matching System`InstanceDump`* found. >>`` on my system.

Comment: @belisarius I see the low-level (and wide effect) `SystemOptions`, but not `Method` options.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Ech, I keep forgetting that you're on version seven...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, you are right. That is the reason why I didn't add it as an answer and started my comment as "Related". I thought the info in the article could be of your interest, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a partial answer.  I believe for `Method -> {opts}`, `opts` may be any of the following, and they will have whatever effect they have:

```
Internal`InequalitySolverOptions[]
Internal`ReduceOptions[]
Internal`NSolveOptions[]
(*
{"ARSDecision" -> False, "BrownProjection" -> True, "CAD" -> True, 
 "CADAlgebraicCoefficients" -> True, "CADBacksubstitution" -> Automatic,
 "CADCombineCells" -> True, "CADConstruction" -> Automatic,
 "CADDefaultPrecision" -> 30.103, "CADExtraPrecision" -> 30.103, "CADMethod" -> Automatic, 
 "CADNRootsMethod" -> Automatic, "CADSortVariables" -> Automatic, 
 "CADZeroTest" -> {0, ∞}, "EquationalConstraintsCAD" -> Automatic, 
 "FGLMBasisConversion" -> False, "FGLMElimination" -> Automatic, 
 "GenericCAD" -> True, "GroebnerCAD" -> True, 
 "LinearDecisionMethodCrossovers" -> {0, 30, 20, Automatic}, 
 "LinearEquations" -> True, "LinearQE" -> True, "LWDecision" -> True, 
 "LWPreprocessor" -> Automatic, "ProjectAlgebraic" -> Automatic, 
 "ProveMultiplicities" -> True, "QuadraticQE" -> Automatic, 
 "QVSPreprocessor" -> False, "ReducePowers" -> Automatic, 
 "RootReduced" -> False, "Simplex" -> True, 
 "SimplifyInequalities" -> Automatic, "ThreadOr" -> True, "ZengDecision" -> False}

{"ADDSolveBound" -> 8, "AlgebraicNumberOutput" -> True, 
 "BDDEliminate" -> Automatic, "BooleanInstanceMethod" -> Automatic, 
 "BranchLinearDiophantine" -> False, "CacheReduceResults" -> Automatic,
 "DiscreteSolutionBound" -> 10, "ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {1000, 10000}, 
 "FactorEquations" -> Automatic, "FactorInequalities" -> False, 
 "FinitePrecisionGB" -> False, "ImplicitIntegerSolutions" -> Automatic, 
 "IntervalRootsOptions" -> {"AllowIncomplete" -> True, "FailDepth" -> 20,
   "MaxDepth" -> 50, "MaxFailures" -> 100, "MaxIncomplete" -> 1000,
   "MaxSimplified" -> 1000, "MaxSteps" -> 100000, "MinPrecision" -> 12}, 
 "LatticeReduceDiophantine" -> True, "LinearEliminationMaxDepth" -> ∞, 
 "MaxFrobeniusGraph" -> 1000000, "MaxModularPoints" -> 1000000, 
 "MaxModularRoots" -> 1000000, "MaxPrimeIndex" -> 1000000000, 
 "NIntegrateTimeConstraint" -> 60, "PresburgerQE" -> Automatic, 
 "QuickReduce" -> False, "RandomInstances" -> Automatic, 
 "RealRootsOptions" -> {"MaxExtensionDegree" -> 5, "MaxFactorSquareFreeDegree" -> 10000, 
   "MaxNestedRootsDegree" -> 100, "SparsityThreshold" -> 0.02}, 
 "ReorderVariables" -> Automatic, "SieveMaxPoints" -> {10000, 1000000}, 
 "SolveDiscreteSolutionBound" -> 1000000, "SyntacticSolveAssumptions" -> False, 
 "TranscendentalRecursionLimit" -> 12, "UseNestedRoots" -> Automatic, 
 "UseOldReduce" -> False, "UseTranscendentalRoots" -> Automatic, 
 "UseTranscendentalSolve" -> True}

{"ComplexEquationMethod" -> Automatic, "MonomialOrder" -> Automatic, 
 "ReorderVariables" -> True, "SelectCriterion" -> (True &), 
 "Tolerance" -> 0, "UseSlicingHyperplanes" -> True}
*)
```

I do not know if there are other settings that may be used.  Building on comments by [belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/belisarius) and [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard), many (or maybe all) of the above are `SystemOptions` that may be passed via the `Method` option to `FindInstance`.  I do not know what all these options do.  Here is an example to show they, or at least one of them, have an effect when passed through the `Method` option (see the discussion of the `"SieveMaxPoints"` option in [Diophantine Polynomial Systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DiophantineReduce.html#623839255) for an example that was the basis for this one):

```
FindInstance[x^2 + 21 y^3 - 17 z^4 == 632, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist. >>

```
FindInstance[x^2 + 21 y^3 - 17 z^4 == 632, {x, y, z}, Integers, 
 Method -> {"SieveMaxPoints" -> {10^4, 10^8}}]
(*  {{x -> -944, y -> 22, z -> 16}}  *)
```

**Update - another example.**  This one is from [Real Polynomial Systems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RealPolynomialSystems.html#4502650) mentioned by @belisarius.  It is the last example in the tutorial and it is supposed to show a case in which `"ZengDecision" -> True` improves the timing.  In that respect things seem to have changed, but the option still has an effect.

```
FindInstance[
  x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4 - 5 x y z w + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 + 1 < 0,
  {x, y, z, w}, Reals] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.140519, {{x -> -6, y -> -5, z -> -6, w -> -4}}}  *)

FindInstance[
  x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4 - 5 x y z w + x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 + 1 < 0,
  {x, y, z, w}, Reals, Method -> "ZengDecision" -> True] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.4111, {{x -> -(7/2), y -> -4, z -> -3, w -> -3}}}  *)
```

Note: There are other `` Internal`*Options `` with corresponding `` Internal`Set*Options ``, which might be used in certain cases of `FindInstance`.
And if not in `FindInstance`, then perhaps they can be used in other functions with an obscure `Method` option.  Each with one exception corresponds to a group of `SystemOptions[]`.

Comment: At least some of those look like they're supposed to be options for `CylindricalDecomposition[]`

Comment: Thanks Michael!  About time this old question got an answer. :-) +1 Necromancer for you.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the accept. I added a little more information that might be used in other `Method` questions, if there are any.