# Possible Method for MatrixExp

Tags: linear-algebra, options, implementation-details, undocumented

Well, probably a hard question, but I think it's better to cry out loud :).

I noticed that `MatrixExp` has a `Method` option when writing [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78578), which is undocumented. Since [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.en.html) claims that *`MatrixExp` uses variable-order Padé approximation, evaluating rational matrix functions using Paterson–Stockmeyer methods or Krylov subspace approximations*, I guess there might exist non-`Automatic` `Method`(s), but I can't find it out. Sadly, techniques in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/1871) seem not to help. Does anyone know? Or is `Automatic` really the only available option?

Comment: I never found an answer to my [own question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6801/121) of a similar nature.  I wonder if the `Method` option is simply added for future extensibility.

Comment: This seems as good an opportunity as any to leave these [two](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1020098) [links](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S00361445024180).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Experimentation based on the documentation you quoted led to two valid Method options:

```
MatrixExp[{{1.2, 5.6}, {3, 4}}, Method -> "Pade"]
```

> ```
> {{346.557, 661.735}, {354.501, 677.425}}
> ```

```
MatrixExp[{{1.2, 5.6}, {3, 4}}, {1, 2}, Method -> "Krylov"]
```

> ```
> {1670.03, 1709.35}
> ```

If `"Krylov"` is used for the single parameter syntax it complains:

```
MatrixExp[{{1.2, 5.6}, {3, 4}}, Method -> "Krylov"]
```

> MatrixExp::novec: The method Krylov requires the specification of a vector. >>

`"Pade"` fails on exact or symbolic input:

```
MatrixExp[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, Method -> "Pade"]
```

> MatrixExp::invmtd: Invalid method Pade for input with precision ∞. >>

Thanks to [ilian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/145/ilian) we now have the last(?) piece of the puzzle:

```
MatrixExp[{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 1}}, Method -> "BlockDecomposition"]
```

> ```
> {{E^2, 0, 0}, {0, E Cos[1], -E Sin[1]}, {0, E Sin[1], E Cos[1]}}
> ```

Comment: From the OP's quote, that would seem to be the only two settings. In particular, the `"Krylov`" setting is valuable for exponentiating sparse matrices, and is quite useful for the [action of the exponential of a sparse matrix on a vector](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/talks/talk10_expab.pdf) (that is, `MatrixExp[A, v, Method -> "Krylov"]` for computing $\exp(\mathbf A)\mathbf v$).

Comment: @J. M. What method do you suppose is used for `MatrixExp[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]` as neither `"Pade"` nor `"Krylov"` is accepted?  (I mean is there something that correlates to `Automatic` in this case.)

Comment: Certainly, one does not use a Padé approximant for computing exact results. A look at [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#14568) tells me that either [Jordan decomposition](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/34130) or [Putzer's algorithm](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2313914) is used.

Comment: @J. M. Neither "Jordan" nor "Putzer" work either.  I am just curious if there is a third valid setting or if whatever is used is only accessible via `Automatic`.  (Oh, and thank you.)

Comment: I'm guessing `MatrixExp[]` is smart enough not to try to compute the eigenvalues of a symbolic matrix (imagine how many `Root[]` objects will that yield!), and will just use Putzer exclusively in that case. For matrices with exact entries, prolly a toss-up, and the precise details are known only to WRI devs.

Comment: On that note, I'm surprised that there is no option to use the Schur decomposition for computing `MatrixExp[]` for inexact matrices, but a little bird told me `MatrixFunction[]` does use Schur. I guess one can use that if one suspects that Padé is returning something weird.

Comment: The third valid setting can be accessed with `Method -> "BlockDecomposition"`.

Comment: @ilian, interesting. That's the Schur-based method, I take it?

Comment: More along the lines of splitting the matrix into blocks and applying the Putzer or Jordan decomposition to each.

Comment: @ilian Thanks!  Added to my answer, with credit of course.

Comment: @ilian, thanks for the detail! If it isn't too revealing, can you tell how `MatrixExp[]` picks between Jordan and Putzer when given a matrix with exact entries?

Comment: Can't really go into more detail on the heuristic, but your guess above is pretty accurate in that all 'non-simple' cases tend to go to Putzer.

Comment: Useful discussions and reponses. I have an inquiry. I am dealing with a very large sparse matrix and its matrix exponential on a vector. I am computing the solution using `MatrixExp[mat, vector, Method -> "Krylov"]; // AbsoluteTiming`, but it is still a bit time-consuming due to a very large size of my matrix. So, I want to know that is there a way to speed up this computation by imposing a tolerance or compiling so as to gain some speed? A result of lower accuracy is OK for me

Comment: @Fazlollah that is probably worth posting as a separate Question if you have not done so already.  I at least don't have an answer for you.