# MatrixExp[m, v] not always faster than MatrixExp[m].v

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

For non sparse matrix `m`, is `MatrixExp[m, v]` supposed to be faster than    `MatrixExp[m].v`? This seems to be true only if `m` is purely real or imaginary.

```
Block[{n = 500},
v = RandomComplex[1. + I, n];
s = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {n, n}];
s1 = RandomComplex[1. + I, {n, n}];
]

MatrixExp[s].v; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.12628, Null}

```
MatrixExp[s, v]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.0379219, Null}

```
MatrixExp[s1].v; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.365637, Null}

```
MatrixExp[s1, v]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{5.17002, Null}

```
MatrixExp[s1, v, Method -> "Krylov"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{4.93712, Null}

```
MatrixExp[s1, v, Method -> "Pade"]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

{0.416058, Null}

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Try quitting kernel between calculations. I'm getting `MatrixExp[s1, v]; // AbsoluteTiming``{5.*10^-6, Null}`

Comment: @Feyre Hi, I tried quitting kernels between calculations and got the same results. What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Curious, now I'm getting slow results too.

Comment: I'm voting to close because I cannot reproduce the issue. If others manage to reproduce this reliably then I'm happy to take back that vote.

Comment: I get very similar results to what the OP shows running his code on V10.4.1 on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: I do not get similar results: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyk1B.png (Mac OSX 10.11.5, V10.4.1)

Comment: Okay, I retracted my vote since this appears to be platform dependent. Will see if we can reproduce it here.

Answer (score 2):

**Mr.Wizard**

Timing results in *Mathematica* **10.1.0** under Windows 7 x64:

> ```
> {0.0660777, Null}
>
> {0.0303608, Null}
>
> {0.190943, Null}
>
> {1.46382, Null}
>
> {1.41635, Null}
>
> {0.183233, Null}
> ```

So I confirm `MatrixExp[s1, v]` and `MatrixExp[s1, v, Method -> "Krylov"]` as being slower on my system.

---

**Alexey Popkov**

Timing results with *Mathematica* **10.4.1** under Windows 7 x64 (CPU with 2 physical cores):

> ```
> {1.26094, Null}
>
> {0.638639, Null}
>
> {1.26434, Null}
>
> {19.7368, Null}
>
> {18.708, Null}
>
> {1.89468, Null}
> ```

---

**Mariusz Iwaniuk**

Timing results with *Mathematica* **10.2.0** under Windows 8.1 x64 (CPU with 2 physical cores):

> ```
> {1.03687, Null}
>
> {0.128066, Null}
>
> {3.9396, Null}
>
> {21.1016, Null}
>
> {21.0798, Null}
>
> {3.95479, Null}
> ```

---

#### ( Use this Community Wiki to share any other timing results of interest. )

Comment: `"Krylov"` is really only good for large, sparse matrices, and mostly intended for use with the action form of the exponential on a vector.

Comment: @J.M. One wonders then why `MatrixExp[s1, v]` seemingly defaults to this method on my system?

Comment: My point was that it is not fair to `"Krylov"` to be using a dense matrix as the argument; of course it will then be slow. Have you also tried [`Method -> "BlockDecomposition"`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83732)?

Comment: @J.M. BlockDecomposition is even slower when I tested it. The slowdown is also present for sparse matrix m.

Comment: @Alexey, can you confirm the OP's observations regarding `"BlockDecomposition"`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, definitely: I wasn't able to measure timing for `"BlockDecomposition"` because it crashed my laptop due to CPU overheating, but it was more than 1 minute...

Comment: I have the same order of timings as Mr.Wizard using 10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit). @J.M. `"BlockDecomposition"` was around 70 times slower then `"Krylov"` for the complex matrix.