# MatrixPower performance

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

In *Mathematica* 9, (I think) `MatrixPower[matrix(m.m), n].vector` has complexity $O(m^{2+\epsilon}\times\log(n))$ (*Mathematica* automatically find the algorithm that optimize the time), while `MatrixPower[matrix(m.m), n, vector]` has complexity $O(m^2\times n)$. It (the second form) always remain that complexity, sometimes it is good and sometimes bad.

For example:

```
mat = Table[RandomReal[1./500], {1000}, {1000}];
vec = Table[RandomReal[1./500], {1000}];

MatrixPower[mat, 1000]; // AbsoluteTiming


(* {6.831456, Null} *)

MatrixPower[mat, 1000, vec]; // AbsoluteTiming


(* {2.889963, Null}*)

MatrixPower[mat, 5000]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {8.150533, Null} *)

MatrixPower[mat, 5000, vec]; // AbsoluteTiming


(* {15.022040, Null}*)
```

In the first case, it is  good, and the second case, it is bad. This seems to be a mistake of the developers.

1. How can I determine the power that optimize the time?
2. Is that fixed in next versions?

Comment: In `10.4` looping over 100 iterations gives me `0.2967,0.1128,0.3945,0.6259` respectively., so persists.

Comment: @Feyre - I take it you divided you're measured times by 100 (or you have a supercomputer)

Comment: @mikado Yes, those are the respective means.

Comment: This question is possibly related to a question I had on `MatrixExp`, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121625/matrixexpm-v-not-always-faster-than-matrixexpm-v