# Tips to help FindInstance with a lot of complicated inequalities

Tags: performance-tuning, inequalities, findinstance

I'm trying to find a numerical instance (I don't need arbitrarily high precision) of solution to 7 relatively complicated inequalities (plus the region specification) involving 8 variables.

The problem is that the kernel quits itself while evaluating the `FindInstance`. I have tried to fix a finite `WorkingPrecision`, to no avail.

I understand that this is probably too little information to even suggest something, but unfortunately I cannot produce a MWE -- the notebook and expressions are too complicated and refer to other files.

Is there any general pointer you could intuitively give me? I was thinking about researching for an ideal `Method`, but don't even know where to begin.

I appreciate any insights.

Comment: This [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6801/9469) is relevant.

Comment: Is there any chance that you could, perhaps by trial and error, pick a subset of your inequalities that constrains where your final solution might be, find the solution to that relaxed problem, and then use that solution to help narrow down the space to look for your full solution?

Comment: Try, if you succed with `cd = CylindricalDecomposition[inequalities, variables] ` . Then `FindInstance[cd, variables] ` is an easy job.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions -- I'll try them as soon as possible.