# Limit the number of the results returned by Solve to some specific number

Tags: equation-solving

I have this Solve:

```
Solve[6x1 + 30x2 + 8x3 + 15x4 - 3x5 + 2x7 == 1325 && -5x1 + 6x4 - x5 + 7x6 + 9x7 == 800 && 10 <= x1 <= 80 && 12 <= x2 <= 146 && 15 <= x3 <= 299 && 9 <= x4 <= 30 && 16 <= x5 <= 172 && 19 <= x6 <= 672 && 8 <= x7 <= 9, {x1, x2, x3, x4,x5, x6, x7}, Integers]
```

It returns 164254 results, which is very long.
Is there a way to limit the number of returns to 100? What I am looking for is a way to avoid situations where Solve wants to return a large amount of data and limit that to some small number, to avoid unnecessary cpu usage. FindInstance is not an options, as it keeps running until I abort:

```
FindInstance[6x1 + 30x2 + 8x3 + 15x4 - 3x5 + 2x7 == 1325 && -5x1 + 6x4 - x5 + 7x6 + 9x7 == 800 && 10 <= x1 <= 80 && 12 <= x2 <= 146 && 15 <= x3 <= 299 && 9 <= x4 <= 30 && 16 <= x5 <= 172 && 19 <= x6 <= 672 && 8 <= x7 <= 9, {x1, x2, x3, x4,x5, x6, x7}, Integers, 100]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. An alternative command to try in this case would be: `FindInstance[x1 + x2 == 1000000, {x1, x2}, PositiveReals, 10]` which gives you 10 results.

Comment: it returns only two results in V 13.3.1, which version are you using?  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eccqB.png)

Comment: I edited my question to reflect on your comments. The first version was a simplified one. I inserted a new system of equations to be solved by Solve[]

Comment: There is no option for Solve to limit the number of solutions. So if `FindInstance` does not work you, then I think you are out of luck. Why not just get all the solutions from Solve and then trim them to the number you want? any way. I do not see an option for what you want with Solve.

Comment: What about MaxExtraConditions option? Do you think it can be of any help?

Comment: I tried it for your example and did not change the result. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HkZD.png)  from reading help: **only solutions that require at most k equational conditions on continuous parameters are included** this option is not meant to limit the number of solutions really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways is as follows.

```
Solve[6 x1 + 30 x2 + 8 x3 + 15 x4 - 3 x5 + 2 x7 == 
1325 && -5 x1 + 6 x4 - x5 + 7 x6 + 9 x7 == 800 && 10 <= x1 <= 80 &&
12 <= x2 <= 146 && 15 <= x3 <= 299 && 9 <= x4 <= 30 && 
16 <= x5 <= 172 && 19 <= x6 <= 672 && 8 <= x7 <= 9, {x1, x2, x3, 
x4, x5, x6, x7}, Integers][[1 ;; 10]]
```

> `{{x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 67, x4 -> 29, x5 -> 28, x6 -> 89,  x7 -> 9}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 70, x4 -> 30, x5 -> 41,  x6 -> 90, x7 -> 9}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 71, x4 -> 27,  x5 -> 28, x6 -> 92, x7 -> 8}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 73,  x4 -> 24, x5 -> 19, x6 -> 92, x7 -> 9}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12,  x3 -> 74, x4 -> 28, x5 -> 41, x6 -> 93, x7 -> 8}, {x1 -> 10,  x2 -> 12, x3 -> 76, x4 -> 25, x5 -> 32, x6 -> 93,  x7 -> 9}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 77, x4 -> 22, x5 -> 19,  x6 -> 95, x7 -> 8}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 77, x4 -> 29,  x5 -> 54, x6 -> 94, x7 -> 8}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 79,  x4 -> 26, x5 -> 45, x6 -> 94, x7 -> 9}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 12,  x3 -> 80, x4 -> 23, x5 -> 32, x6 -> 96, x7 -> 8}}`

Comment: This is interesting. It actually solves for all the solutions, but only returns the first 10 ones. right? BTW, do you think `Method->` can be of any help here? `Solve` and `FindInstance`, probably, are using different methods to solve this system of equations. If one knows what `Method` is `Solve` using and add that to `FindInstance`, it is likely to work. Although I know that the Methods used by Mathematica are not public.

Comment: The only described method of `Solve` is `Method->Reduce`. Its application  here does no effect.

Comment: Here [What Method options does FindInstance accept?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6801/what-method-options-does-findinstance-accept) it was discussed, but there are too many options available. I don't think it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to get less solutions is to make your constraints tighter. Here I change the first constraint to be `10<=x[1]<=10` instead of `10<x[1]<80`, and I do the same with the constraint on `x[2]`

```
A = {{6, 30, 8, 15, -3, 0, 2},
   {-5, 0, 0, 6, -1, 7, 9}};
b = {1325, 800};
xArr = Array[x, 7];
cons = 10 <= x[1] <= 80 && 12 <= x[2] <= 146 && 15 <= x[3] <= 299 && 
   9 <= x[4] <= 30 && 16 <= x[5] <= 172 && 19 <= x[6] <= 672 && 
   8 <= x[7] <= 9;
cons[[1, -1]] = 10;
cons[[2, -1]] = 12;
sol = Solve[A . xArr == b && cons, Integers];
Length@sol
(*122*)
```

This is not great really, because this is a very specific region of the solutions. A random sample from the constrained solution space is probably more what you want, but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

Notice however that since this is just a linear system, we can find one solution to the problem, and any other solution will be that solution plus the matrix's null space (dotted with a vector):

```
(*find one solution on the integers*)
f0 = FindInstance[A . xArr == b, xArr, Integers] // Values // Flatten;
(*any other solution will be f0 plus a vector dotted with the null \
space*)
ns = NullSpace[A];
kArr = Array[k, Length@ns];
solnForm = kArr . ns + Threaded[f0];
(*since the null space has 5 vectors we reduce to a 5 variable \
constrained solution*)
constrained = 
 Table[cons[[i]] /. xArr[[i]] -> solnForm[[i]], {i, Length@solnForm}]

(*{10 <= 135 k[1] + 35 k[2] - 10 k[3] + 60 k[4] <= 80, 
 12 <= -32 k[1] - 7 k[2] + 7 k[3] - 37 k[4] - 4 k[5] <= 146, 
 15 <= 15 k[5] <= 299, 9 <= 50 k[4] <= 30, 16 <= 7 + 50 k[3] <= 172, 
 19 <= -750 + 25 k[2] <= 672, 8 <= 673 + 75 k[1] <= 9}*)
```

Maybe there is some way to use this to find more randomly-spaced solutions in your constrained solution space?

Comment: One of the results of `sol = Solve[A . xArr == b && cons, Integers]` is `{x[1] -> 10, x[2] -> 12, x[3] -> 154, x[4] -> 9, x[5] -> 160, 
 x[6] -> 125, x[7] -> 9}`. Now `(6 x1 + 30 x2 + 8 x3 + 15 x4 - 3 x5 + 2 x7 == 
    1325 && -5 x1 + 6 x4 - x5 + 7 x6 + 9 x7 == 800 && 10 <= x1 <= 80 &&
    12 <= x2 <= 146 && 15 <= x3 <= 299 && 9 <= x4 <= 30 && 
   16 <= x5 <= 172 && 19 <= x6 <= 672 && 8 <= x7 <= 9) /. {x[1] -> 10,
   x[2] -> 12, x[3] -> 154, x[4] -> 9, x[5] -> 160, x[6] -> 125, 
  x[7] -> 9}` results in

Comment: `6 x1 + 30 x2 + 8 x3 + 15 x4 - 3 x5 + 2 x7 == 
  1325 && -5 x1 + 6 x4 - x5 + 7 x6 + 9 x7 == 800 && 10 <= x1 <= 80 && 
 12 <= x2 <= 146 && 15 <= x3 <= 299 && 9 <= x4 <= 30 && 
 16 <= x5 <= 172 && 19 <= x6 <= 672 && 8 <= x7 <= 9`, not `True`.

Comment: I am using `x[1], x[2],...,x[7]` for variable names instead of `x1,x2,...,x7` for variable names (I did this because it felt easier to just write `xArr = Array[x, 7];`). If you change my variables back to their original names (`x1,x2,...,x7`) it works:
$$ $$
`(6 x1 + 30 x2 + 8 x3 + 15 x4 - 3 x5 + 2 x7 == 
    1325 && -5 x1 + 6 x4 - x5 + 7 x6 + 9 x7 == 800 && 10 <= x1 <= 80 &&
    12 <= x2 <= 146 && 15 <= x3 <= 299 && 9 <= x4 <= 30 && 
   16 <= x5 <= 172 && 19 <= x6 <= 672 && 8 <= x7 <= 9) /. {x1 -> 10, 
  x2 -> 12, x3 -> 154, x4 -> 9, x5 -> 160, x6 -> 125, x7 -> 9}`

`(*True*)`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I should've specified I changed the names of the variables.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It is not so simple. How "to make your constraints tighter" if one wants 15 solutions? 360 items?  My code takes 11.2831 s, not so much.

Comment: `(k[1], k[2], k[3], k[4], k[5])` form a vector space whose vectors are the solutions to unconstrained system `A . xArr == b`. But finding those vectors which satisfy the constraints is not trivial.