# Return only one numeric solution to equation

Tags: syntax

Consider a simple plane equation

```
2x-3y+4z==7
```

I just want some position vector on that plane. For example, `{7/2,0,0}` would be great.

How can I ask Mathematica for 'some point' on this plane? The best I've got right now is:

```
Solve[plane && y == 0 && z == 0, x]
```

But I don't actually care what the values of y and z are, I just want some random point that satisfies the plane equation. Also that just returns the value of x - I want all three values in a vector (list?) form {a, b, c}.

Comment: There are quite literally an infinite number of points on that plane. You have to give *some* criteria for which point you want.

Comment: And if I asked you to pick a random integer, could you do that? Could a computer? I think my question is pretty reasonable, and if the answer insists I put some bounds on the values, that's fine too.

Comment: Related: [(9734)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9734/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindInstance.html):

```
{x,y,z} /. FindInstance[2 x - 3 y + 4 z == 7, {x, y, z}, Reals, 5]
```

> ```
> {{-22, 8/5, 279/20},
>  {-(109/5), 11/5, 143/10},
>  {8/5, 2, 49/20},
>  {42/5, 82/5, 197/20},
>  {149/10, -(11/2), -(393/40)}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Since Henry said "I don't actually care what the values of y and z are" I am editing this to leave out those conditions, and show the output. (+1 of course.)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_on_plane_closest_to_origin

In Euclidean space, the point on a plane ax + by + cz = d that is closest to the origin has the Cartesian coordinates (x,y,z), where:

x = ad/(a^2+b^2+c^2)

y = bd/(a^2+b^2+c^2)

z = cd/(a^2+b^2+c^2)

Since you know a=2, b=-3, c=4, and d=-7, you can get {x,y,z} on your plane using these three equations.

Comment: I guess that does give a point, and I could translate it into Mathematica. But this is not really what the question was asking. This works great though: FindInstance[2 x - 3 y + 4 z == 7, {x, y, z}]