# FindInstance (and Solve, ...) abysmally slow on a fully determined system of linear equations and inequalities: why?

Tags: equation-solving

I took a quick look for `FindInstance` and `Solve`-related questions but came up empty for the aspect that I am curious about. So here is my newbie question:

```
FindInstance[{
  s==9,r==8,d==7,n==6,e==5,y==2,m==1,o==0
},{s,e,n,d,m,o,r,y},Integers]
```

runs as quickly as one would expect. But

```
FindInstance[{
  s!=e!=n!=d!=m!=o!=r!=y,
  s==9,r==8,d==7,n==6,e==5,y==2,m==1,o==0
},{s,e,n,d,m,o,r,y},Integers]
```

takes ages -- long enough that I ran out of patience before MMA was done.

And now I am curious: Why would *Mathematica* suddenly display less maths ability than a third-grader?

---

bill_s suggested something much faster, but it is not equivalent to the original problem. The original inequality required all variable values to be different from all other variable values, such that each value can only be used for one variable. The FindInstance statement in Bill's post only compares x[i] to the i<sup>th</sup> value, but not to the other n-1 values.

In other news,

```
FindInstance[{
  (*s!=e,s!=n,s!=d,s!=m,s!=o,s!=r,s!=y,*)
  (*e!=n,e!=d,e!=m,e!=o,e!=r,e!=y,*)
  n!=d,n!=m,n!=o,n!=r,n!=y,
  d!=m,d!=o,d!=r,d!=y,
  m!=o,m!=r,m!=y,
  o!=r,o!=y,
  r!=y,
  s==9,r==8,d==7,n==6,e==5,y==2,m==1,o==0
  },{s,e,n,d,m,o,r,y},Integers]
```

~1.1 seconds (on my laptop).

```
FindInstance[{
  (*s!=e,s!=n,s!=d,s!=m,s!=o,s!=r,s!=y,*)
  e!=n,e!=d,e!=m,e!=o,e!=r,e!=y,
  n!=d,n!=m,n!=o,n!=r,n!=y,
  d!=m,d!=o,d!=r,d!=y,
  m!=o,m!=r,m!=y,
  o!=r,o!=y,
  r!=y,
  s==9,r==8,d==7,n==6,e==5,y==2,m==1,o==0
  },{s,e,n,d,m,o,r,y},Integers]
```

2nd comment uncommentd. ~20 s.

```
FindInstance[{
  s!=e,s!=n,s!=d,s!=m,s!=o,s!=r,s!=y,
  e!=n,e!=d,e!=m,e!=o,e!=r,e!=y,
  n!=d,n!=m,n!=o,n!=r,n!=y,
  d!=m,d!=o,d!=r,d!=y,
  m!=o,m!=r,m!=y,
  o!=r,o!=y,
  r!=y,
  s==9,r==8,d==7,n==6,e==5,y==2,m==1,o==0
  },{s,e,n,d,m,o,r,y},Integers]
```

Both comments uncommented. ~1 minute.

The original version (multiple inequalities in one condition):

```
Timing[FindInstance[{
    s!=e!=n!=d!=m!=o!=r!=y,
    s==9,r==8,d==7,n==6,e==5,y==2,m==1,o==0},
    {s,e,n,d,m,o,r,y},Integers]]
```

150 seconds!

Comment: Related: [FindInstance with a Diophantine equation seems to go on forever](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3554/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, that was one of the questions I came across, and there, at least, MMA had the excuse of actually having to do a little bit of work. :-)

Comment: Okay, I didn't know if you had seen it.  I agree that the behavior you illustrate is enigmatic, and I don't have an explanation for it.  In this particular case you could use `Reduce @ {s != e != n != d != m != o != r != y, s == 9, r == 8, d == 7, n == 6, e == 5, 
  y == 2, m == 1, o == 0}` to remove the inequalities, but this operation itself takes much longer than it arguably should.  I would have expected both of your examples to be either fast or slow, rather than one of each.  (continued)

Comment: Both could have been slow if `FindInstance` ignored the "obvious" values and began a brute-force search, but since it apparently recognizes these in the first example I don't know why it does not in the second.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `a1!=a2!=a3!=a4!=a5` is fine. Add `!=a6`, and MMA is off to the beach. Or add `,a5!=a6` (far less of a constraint), same thing. In short, I'll remember that it's cheaper to generate a large list of candidate solution by omitting some inequality constraints and to filter the list afterwards. Thanks for your remark on `Reduce`, which reminded me of the possibility of not including the constraints in the first place.

Comment: Odd, I just ran the second, problematic example, in m9.0.1 on win7-64 and it returned {{s -> 9, e -> 5, n -> 6, d -> 7, m -> 1, o -> 0, r -> 8, y -> 2}} in 128.6 seconds.  Which is slow but not quite "ages".

Comment: FindInstance went with a heuristic method choice that was far from optimal. Next version should be better..

Comment: @Ymareth -- I consider 130 seconds to be ages when the task at hand is a list of eight simple assignments. :) I have added timings to the original post, showing an interesting difference between the `a!=b!=c!=...` form and the `a!=b,a!=c,a!=d,...,b!=c,b!=d,...,c!=d,...` form.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau -- Thanks! As I just mentioned to Ymareth, "I have added timings to the original post, showing an interesting difference between the `a!=b!=c!=...` form and the `a!=b,a!=c,a!=d,...,b!=c,b!=d,...,c!=d,...` form." The  latter takes, for eight vars, 2.5 times as long as the longhand version. The multiplicative factor in the timing here seems to grow more than linearly. (And how does one say that last in correct English? Sorry!)

Comment: @Felix Kasza.  It is puzzling I agree but the original form of the question (on which I was commenting) gave no timings or context and (read a certain way) implied that mathematica was failing ("Why would Mathematica suddenly display less maths ability than a third-grader?" - this implies inability NOT tardiness) to solve the problem even after a very long period of time.  Failing to solve and failing to solve quickly are not the same thing.

Comment: @Felix What you wrote is clear in English. As for the reason, I believe the number of explicit inequalities figures into the method choice heuristic so that could be the cause of worse-than-linear complexity.

Comment: @Ymareth -- Thanks. I'll attempt to be more precise in my initial question next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one has upgraded this post in a long time and as Danny promised all the problems the OP posted have been dealt with. In v 11.1 for instance, the last one now runs in a lot less than 150 seconds.

```
Timing[FindInstance[{
    s!=e!=n!=d!=m!=o!=r!=y,
    s==9,r==8,d==7,n==6,e==5,y==2,m==1,o==0},
    {s,e,n,d,m,o,r,y},Integers]]


{0.01, {{s -> 9, e -> 5, n -> 6, d -> 7, m -> 1, o -> 0, r -> 8, y -> 2}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the comments, [Daniel Lichtblau wrote](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41562/findinstance-and-solve-abysmally-slow-on-a-fully-determined-system-of-lin#comment125202_41562):

> [...] I believe the number of explicit inequalities figures into the method choice heuristic so that could be the cause of worse-than-linear complexity.

So it would seem that `FindInstance` made an unfortunate choice in tackling this, admittedly odd, set of inequalities.

One possible work-around would be to use smaller, non-overlapping, subsets of inequalities: `a!=b!=c!=d&&e!=f!=g!=h` and to filter the solution set returned by `FindInstance`.

Comment: There is no provision for marking a comment as an answer.  If after encouraging the comment's author to post it as an answer he does not, it is entirely appropriate to make it into an answer yourself as you did here.  (Though I would copy the comment verbatim.)

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an extended comment than a genuine answer... but consider this generalization of the problem:

```
n = 10;
xVec = Array[x, n];
vals = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, n];
FindInstance[Thread[xVec == vals], xVec]
FindInstance[Thread[xVec != vals], xVec]
Flatten[{Thread[xVec[[1 ;; n/2]] != vals[[1 ;; n/2]]], 
         Thread[xVec[[n/2 + 1 ;; n]] == vals[[n/2 + 1 ;; n]]]}]

{{x[1] -> 10, x[2] -> 7, x[3] -> 5, x[4] -> 4, x[5] -> 4, x[6] -> 8, 
  x[7] -> 5, x[8] -> 0, x[9] -> 3, x[10] -> 3}}
{{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, 
  x[7] -> 0, x[8] -> 1, x[9] -> 0, x[10] -> 0}}
{x[1] != 7, x[2] != 2, x[3] != 2, x[4] != 2, x[5] != 3, x[6] == 3, 
 x[7] == 6, x[8] == 5, x[9] == 1, x[10] == 6}
```

Moreover, it works quite well for even large size problems:

```
n = 500;
xVec = Array[x, n];
vals = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, n];
First[FindInstance[Thread[xVec == vals], xVec] // Timing]
First[FindInstance[Thread[xVec != vals], xVec] // Timing]
First[Flatten[{Thread[xVec[[1 ;; n/2]] != vals[[1 ;; n/2]]], 
               Thread[xVec[[n/2 + 1 ;; n]] == vals[[n/2 + 1 ;; n]]]}] // Timing]

2.449844
0.911796
0.000378
```

Why is the last one so fast compared to the others? It doesn't matter if you rearrange the orders of the three tests. Maybe the slowness has to do with the specific variable names and/or values chosen?

Comment: Too long for a comment, I'll try amending the original post ...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it takes long time, however, this works quite fast.

```
Assuming[s != e != n != d != m != o != r != y, 
FindInstance[{s == 9, r == 8, d == 7, n == 6, e == 5, y == 2, m == 1, o == 0},
{s, e, n, d, m, o, r, y}, Integers]]
```

Comment: I don't think `FindInstance` uses assumptions; if so, this would be equivalent to the OP's first example.

Answer (score 1):

The following is just my guess.
Usually `!=` is not dealt with directly, it is broken into `a<b || a>b`. Then it's natural that the number of cases grows exponentially.