# FindInstance boolean program is slow, but fast with BooleanConvert

Tags: boolean-computation, findinstance

`FindInstance` can be incredibly slow to solve a boolean program, but it can be significantly improved by using `BooleanConvert` to convert the constraints to "conjunctive normal form".

For example, here is a boolean program with some random constraints. My laptop can't solve it in 10 seconds.

```
vars = Array[x, 50];
SeedRandom[1234];
const = And @@ Table[Or[
     Xor[RandomChoice[vars], RandomChoice[vars]],
     Xor[RandomChoice[vars], RandomChoice[vars]]], 100];

TimeConstrained[FindInstance[const, vars, Booleans], 10, "Timeout!"]

(* Timeout! *)
```

Converting the constraints to "conjunctive normal form" helps `FindInstance` find a solution almost instantly:

```
AbsoluteTiming@FindInstance[ BooleanConvert[const,"CNF"], vars, Booleans ] // Short

(* {0.014715, {{x[1] -> False, x[2] -> False, <<46>>, x[49] -> False, x[50] -> False}}} *)
```

[Wolfram's 4-color map-coloring example](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/entity-based-geocomputation/find-a-four-coloring-of-a-map-of-europe.html) uses this trick; without `BooleanConvert`, it takes forever to run.

Does anyone know why this is so? I wish the `FindInstance` documentation would've mentioned this trick.

Related: [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3554/findinstance-with-a-diophantine-equation-seems-to-go-on-forever), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41562/findinstance-and-solve-abysmally-slow-on-a-fully-determined-system-of-lin)

**Update:** A colleague pointed out that "conjunctive normal form" has the appealing property that it allows short-circuiting, which allows the satisfiability solver to prune away large branches of the tree of candidate variable choices. For example,

```
BooleanConvert[Nand[x, y]~And~Xor[y, z], "CNF"]
```

converts the expression into the AND of a bunch of OR expressions:

```
(! x || ! y) && (! y || ! z) && (y || z)
```

When testing a candidate set of values for `x,y,z`, the solver can evaluate each OR expression in turn and stop as soon as it encounters one that evaluates to FALSE. For example, once it concludes that `x=TRUE, y=TRUE` makes the first OR clause FALSE, it can prune off the lower levels of the tree and doesn't need to try either value of `z`.

Comment: Hi; the problems in your second link have been repaired.

Comment: @bobbym, thanks a bunch.

Comment: I would like to see a lot more documentation on this command and of a simpler nature. Sometimes it just loses me. +1