# How to merge permutations obtained from Solve on multiple variables?

Tags: equation-solving, permutation, diophantine-equations

When I compute the following expression to find integer solutions of the equation `(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^2)`

```
Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^2 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

Mathematica returns

```
{{x -> 4, y -> 6, z -> 12}, {x -> 4, y -> 12, z -> 6}, {x -> 6, y -> 4, z -> 12}, 
 {x -> 6, y -> 12, z -> 4}, {x -> 12, y -> 4, z -> 6}, {x -> 12, y -> 6, z -> 4}}
```

which are permutations of the only solution: x=4, y=6, z=12.

How can I remove other "solutions" by somehow merging the permutations? For me, x, y, and z are equivalent.

---

I don't want to do the following:

```
First[Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^2 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers]]
```

Because I will also solve:

```
Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^3 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers]
```

which has more than one solution.

---

Edit (by belisarius)

Is there a way to specify the equivalency to `Solve[]` or `Reduce[]` so to spare the results post-processing stage?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Related: [(3554)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3554/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DeleteDuplicates`, `DeleteDuplicatesBy` (Version 10)  or `GatherBy` as follows:

```
ddF = DeleteDuplicates[#, Sort[Last /@ #] == Sort[Last /@ #2] &] &;
ddbF = DeleteDuplicatesBy[#,Sort[Last/@#]&]&;
fgbF = First /@ GatherBy[#, Sort[Last /@ #] &] &;
```

Examples:

```
sol1 = Solve[ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^2 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers];
sol2 = Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^3 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers];

ddF[sol1]
(* {{x -> 4, y -> 6, z -> 12}} *)

ddF[sol2]
(* {{x -> 2, y -> 6, z -> 52}, {x -> 2, y -> 36, z -> 38}, 
    {x -> 10,  y -> 12, z -> 50}, {x -> 12, y -> 22, z -> 46},
    {x -> 12, y -> 34,  z -> 38}, {x -> 14, y -> 28, z -> 42},
    {x -> 18, y -> 22,  z -> 44}, {x -> 20, y -> 30, z -> 38}} *)
```

`ddbF` and `fgbF` produce the same output.

Answer (score 4):

For the given problem it is better to use [`PowersRepresentations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowersRepresentations.html) or  [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html) which not only avoid the problem but are far faster as well:

```
IntegerPartitions[14^2, {3}, Range[14]^2] // Sqrt
```

> ```
> {{12, 6, 4}}
> ```

```
PowersRepresentations[14^2, 3, 2] ~DeleteCases~ {___, 0, ___}
```

> ```
> {{4, 6, 12}}
> ```

And for your second example:

```
IntegerPartitions[14^3, {3}, Range[53]^2] // Sqrt
```

> ```
> {{52, 6, 2}, {50, 12, 10}, {46, 22, 12}, {44, 22, 18},
>  {42, 28, 14}, {38, 36, 2}, {38, 34, 12}, {38, 30, 20}}
> ```

```
PowersRepresentations[14^3, 3, 2] ~DeleteCases~ {___, 0, ___}
```

> ```
> {{2, 6, 52}, {2, 36, 38}, {10, 12, 50}, {12, 22, 46},
>  {12, 34, 38}, {14, 28, 42}, {18, 22, 44}, {20, 30, 38}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Your two example equations are symmetric with respect to $x$, $y$, and $z$. The symmetry leads to the redundancy you want to avoid. Rather than calculate all possible redundant solutions and delete duplicates, you could impose an extra constraint, $x\le y\le z$, to eliminate the duplicates. Hence,

```
Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^2 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && x <= y <= z, 
      {x, y, z}, Integers][[All, All, 2]]

{{4, 6, 12}}
```

and

```
Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^3 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && x <= y <= z,
      {x, y, z}, Integers][[All, All, 2]]

{{2, 6, 52}, {2, 36, 38}, {10, 12, 50}, {12, 22, 46}, {12, 34, 38},
 {14, 28, 42}, {18, 22, 44}, {20, 30, 38}}
```

Mr.Wizard's answer, which uses `IntegerPartitions` and `PowersRepresentations`, implicitly avoids the redundancy.

Comment: This is very natural and doesn't involve another function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach this is to find all the answers, sort the numbers, and then remove the duplicates:

```
sol = Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^2 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers];
Union@Map[Sort, sol[[All, All, 2]], 1]
```

which returns the unique solution for the three variables. For the 14^3 problem, the same procedure returns a collection of distinct answers

```
sol = Solve[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 14^3 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Integers];
Union@Map[Sort, sol[[All, All, 2]], 1]

{{2, 6, 52}, {2, 36, 38}, {10, 12, 50}, {12, 22, 46}, {12, 34, 38}, 
 {14, 28, 42}, {18, 22, 44}, {20, 30, 38}}
```